# Display member details based on their age using LINQ and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to check for people in a certain age range. I have two ComboBoxes, minagecombobox and maxagecombobox, with values between 1 and 120.

I want to get the people whose age is between these two values (suppose for example I want to filter out the people aged between 18 and 24).

This is the Member table structure:

```
member_id
member_firstname
member_dob(datatype is string)
```

And my entity name is dbcontext. I am using Entity Framework and LINQ to Entities.

Answer (score 0):

```
DoBConverted = (Today's date - age(in years)) // in datetime
```

would give you the date of birth.

Simiarly, parse DoB (string) to get datetime.

You can perform a check with dob value with min dob and max dob to get the records.

```
int minAge = 18, maxAge=20;
DateTime convertedMinDob = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-minAge);
DateTime convertedMaxDob = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-maxAge);
Console.WriteLine(convertedMinDob.ToString() + " " + convertedMaxDob.ToString());

string strDate = "1/1/1995";
DateTime actualDate = DateTime.Parse(strDate);

bool valid = actualDate >= convertedMaxDob && actualDate <= convertedMinDob;

Console.WriteLine(valid? "In range": "Out of range");
```

Comment: You can add a new property in entity frameework for DoB of datatype datetime as DateTime.Parse(member_Dob)

Comment: unfortunately i cant add any property to entity , would you pls suggest any other way to do that ..

Comment: @errorstacks, you can use the linq query provided by alex. You don't have to create a property.

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate the age and compare it with your desired age interval. The age calculation isn't exactly the best, but it's good enough as an example:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
int min = 18, max = 20;

var res = 
    from m in Member
    let Age = System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.DateDiff("y", t.member_dob, now)
    where Age >= min && Age <= max
    select m;
```

Comment: Many thanks but got an error  like this notsupportedexception ......The specified method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] DateDiff(System.String, System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' on the type 'System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression...

Comment: @errorstacks That seems a bit strange, considering that the `DateDiff` function can only be used with LINQ to Entities.

Comment: would you pls suggest any alternative solution